3-Hitting-Set with 3-Approximation
The 3-Hitting-Set Problem is defined as a set $F$ of 3-element subsets of a ground set $U$ with size $|U| = n$, and the goal is to find the smallest subset $S \subseteq U$ such that $S$ has a non-empty intersection with each set in $F$, i.e., for each $f \in F$, it holds that $f \cap S \ne \emptyset$.
Now it is asked to provide a factor-3 approximation algorithm that runs in polynomial time and prove the correctness of the approximation factor.
Greedy-Algoritm

Let $R = F$
WHILE $R \ne \emptyset$:
Choose the element that hits the most sets in $R$ and remove all the sets hit from $R$.
Return chosed elements.

How can we show, that the solution of this algorithm is maximum three times larger than the optimal solution?

Thanks. I've changed it in the question.
